# Insert and move multiple images via jQuery AJAX in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, mysqli, upload

view:

```
$("#submit").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    product_name = $("#product_name").val();
    category = $("#category").val();
    var formData = new FormData();
    $.each($("#product_image"), function (i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files, function (j, file) {                    
            formData.append('product_image[' + i + ']', file);
        });
    });
    formData.append('product_name', product_name);
    formData.append('category', category);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/products",
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function products()
{
    $dataInfo = array();
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['product_image']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['product_image']['name']= $files['product_image']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['product_image']['type']= $files['product_image']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name']= $files['product_image']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['product_image']['error']= $files['product_image']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['product_image']['size']= $files['product_image']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();
    }

    $data = array(

            'product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
            'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
            'product_image' => implode(",",array_column($dataInfo, 'product_image'))
        );
    $sql = $this->db->insert('add_product',$data);
    if($sql == true)
    {
        echo 'New Product Added';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Unable to Proceed!';
    }
}

private function set_upload_options()
{   
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = ''.base_url().'resource/product/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
    return $config;
}
```

I have three input field i.e. `product_name,category and product_image`. Now, I wants to move multiple images and insert `product_image` name which is separated by comma(,) for example `img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg` like that. Now, when I alert reponse it show nothing. So, How can I solve ? Please help me.

expected output demo of mysql like

```
product_name    category    product_images
============    ========    ==============
men t-shirt     MEN         img1.jp,img2.jpg,img3.jpg
kids t-shirt    kids        img1.jp,img2.jpg,img3.jpg
```

Comment: I have update my code, Now only `product_name and category` value are store in database but image are not inserted and not move into folder

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($dataInfo);`?

Comment: it only insert `product_name` and `category` and `product_image` are not inserted and not move into the folder.

Comment: If I print `$cpt` it count only `1` while I am select 3 images at a time

Comment: You got me wrong, i want to know if you got your files correctly, so let me rephrase, what is the result of  `var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: array(1) { ["product_image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(42) "s-7-shapphr-original-imaetxzzsnbnzfmz.jpeg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phppkemKD" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(33178) } } } @SherifSalah

Comment: that's only one file!

Comment: yes, but I want to upload multiple file @SherifSalah

Comment: Btw .. the upload path should be like this `$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'resource/product/';`

Comment: that's what i'm talking about, you only passed one file so you have a problem with you html/js code.

Comment: So, How can I insert and move multiple image. Please help me @SherifSalah

Comment: i've explained everything in details in my answer bro.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here a complete answer from A to Z of how to upload multiple files using ajax, first of all in the view, you can put as many file inputs as you want but as an array of course like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url('') ?>" method="post">
    <input name="files[]" type="file" />
    <input name="files[]" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" id="upload"/>
</form>
```

Then your ajax like this, no overhead whatsoever, just a normal submission:

```
$('#upload').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {

        },
        error: function(response) {

        }
    });
});
```

But this code will pass `$_FILES` like this:

```
array(1) {
    ["files"]=>
    array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(10) "imgOne.jpg"
            [1]=>
            string(31) "imgTwo.png"
        }
        ["type"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(10) "image/jpeg"
            [1]=>
            string(9) "image/png"
        }
        ["tmp_name"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF867.tmp"
            [1]=>
            string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF878.tmp"
        }
        ["error"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            int(0)
            [1]=>
            int(0)
        }
        ["size"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            int(358419)
            [1]=>
            int(72657)
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the problem, so we have to rearrange this array in your controller's method like this:

```
$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $property => $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $files[$key][$property] = $value;
    }
}
```

And this will give you a proper array like this:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(10) "imgOne.jpg"
        ["type"]=>
        string(10) "image/jpeg"
        ["tmp_name"]=>
        string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF867.tmp"
        ["error"]=>
        int(0)
        ["size"]=>
        int(358419)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(31) "imgTwo.png"
        ["type"]=>
        string(9) "image/png"
        ["tmp_name"]=>
        string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF878.tmp"
        ["error"]=>
        int(0)
        ["size"]=>
        int(72657)
    }
}
```

**Now** you can loop through this array and `do_upload` with CodeIgniter, but first lets reinitialize our `$_FILES` with the new array and then load upload library with our configs and loop through it like this:

```
$_FILES = $files;
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '2048';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
foreach ($_FILES as $fieldname => $fileobject)
{
    if (!empty($fileobject['name']))
    {
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($fieldname))
        {
            $errors[$fileobject['name']] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            $success[$fileobject['name']] = 'Success';
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ajax request is not success at all. I mean there are some errors in the middle process of uploading the image. Try add `error` option on your ajax declaration.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:formData,
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/products",
    success: function(response) { // <-- will called if http response is 200
        //console.log(response);
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {  // <-- will called if any error in server. http response: 400, 500, etc
        //console.error(response);
        alert(response);
    }

});
```

Don't forget to enable your php error reporting and also checking the php error log will give you more information

Comment: see @DharmaSaputra now, only `product_images` are not inserted and move into folder and database